# Flag Comment form z-index / opacity issue

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface, comment-flags

I had tried flagging a comment in Stack Overflow, which was the last one before the answer input form area and I noticed a strange `z-index` issue:

[image: preview]

This thing happens even in Meta. I just checked it now. The reason being there are a few inline styles, which make it display that way. It was hard to replicate, but it was possible:

[image: source]

Is this a known bug, or?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, it may be 100% duplicate, but has to be fixed right? Should I accept the duplicate and close it or wait for our  beloved [Sklivvz](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/131112/sklivvz) to come and respond?

Comment: Why Skilvvz of all devs? Anyway, as long as there's no status tag, the bug is open so no point leaving other same reports open as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have seen only that dev actively responding. That's why. I don't think we as users can add `status-` tags, isn't it?

Comment: That is correct, but you missed Marc Gravell bug fix spree last week. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ooh, what's that? I am not so active in MSE.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/23354/marc-gravell): https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUMt7.png (all 8 answers are bug fixes, in 3 days he was on bug watch.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Wow... Awesome. I didn't know such a person existed. :)

Comment: Yeah, Oded also get this "bug fix spree" sometimes... dunno what triggers it though.

Comment: Ha ha ha... They might be ultimately free or in a vengeance to fix all the bugs...